# Java: StreamCorruptedException na serialização/deserialização de objetos

Tags: java, exceção, serialização

Estou realizando um exercício envolvendo serialização e desserialização em Java. Na execução do programa estou recebendo o seguinte erro no console da IDE (NetBeans):

```
set 08, 2018 5:07:53 PM testeserializador.Serializador desserializar
Nome: sabão em pó
GRAVE: null
Valor: 10.44
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1381)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at testeserializador.Serializador.desserializar(Serializador.java:66)
at testeserializador.TesteSerializador.main2(TesteSerializador.java:22)
at testeserializador.TesteSerializador.main(TesteSerializador.java:9)
```

Já pesquisei outras perguntas similares, mas tudo que eu achei envolvia o uso de conexão de Internet, sockets e afins, sendo que o meu programa é bem mais simples que isso. Outras fontes diziam que o problema estava na criação de uma segunda instância de ObjectOutputStream. Só que já testei criar somente uma instância de ObjectOutputStream a cada execução do programa e mesmo assim ocorre esse mesmo erro.

Segue o programa que está dando problema.

Classe TesteSerializador(contendo método main):

```
public class TesteSerializador {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        main1();
        main1(); ///Se apagar o "dados.dat" e retirar essa linha o programa funciona sem erros
        main2();
    }

    public static void main1(){
        GerenciadorProduto gProd = new GerenciadorProduto();
        gProd.produtoConstruir("sabão em pó", 10.44);
        Serializador ser = new Serializador(gProd);
        ser.serializar();
    }

    public static void main2(){
        GerenciadorProduto gProd = new GerenciadorProduto();
        Serializador ser = new Serializador(gProd);
        ser.desserializar();  
        gProd.produtosExibir();
    }
}
```

Classe Serializador:

```
public class Serializador {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    FileInputStream fis;
    ObjectInputStream ois;

    GerenciadorProduto gProd;

    Produto produto;

    public Serializador(GerenciadorProduto gProd) {
        this.gProd = gProd;

        try{
            fos = new FileOutputStream("dados.dat", true);

            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Serializador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Serializador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void serializar(){
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("dados.dat", true);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            for(Produto produtoIt : gProd.produtos){
                oos.writeObject(produtoIt);
            }

            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Serializador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Serializador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    public void desserializar(){
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("dados.dat");
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);


            while(true){
                produto = (Produto) ois.readObject(); //é na segunda leitura que a exceção é lançada

                if(produto != null){
                    gProd.produtoAdicionar(produto);
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }

            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Serializador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            if(ex instanceof EOFException){
                System.out.println("Fim do arquivo!");

                return;
            }

            Logger.getLogger(Serializador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Serializador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Classe Produto:

```
public class Produto implements Serializable{
    String nome;
    double valor;

    public Produto(String nome, double valor) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.valor = valor;
    }
}
```

Classe GerenciadorProduto:

```
public class GerenciadorProduto {
    List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList();

    public void produtoConstruir(String nome, double valor){
        produtos.add(new Produto(nome, valor));
    }
    public void produtoAdicionar(Produto produto){
        produtos.add(produto);
    }
    public void produtosExibir(){
        for(Produto produto : produtos){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Nome: "+produto.nome);
            System.out.println("Valor: "+produto.valor);
        }
    }
}
```

Para clarificar, se eu deletar "data.dat" (para "começar do zero") e subtitua o método main() na classe TesteSerializador por

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    main1();
    //main1(); ///Se apagar o "dados.dat" e retirar essa linha o programa funciona sem erros
    main2();
}
```

O programa vai lançar a exceção na segunda execução (na primeira roda normalmente).

Comment: Você tentou debuggar linha a linha esse codigo? Porque debuggando, nenhum erro ocorre e o codigo executa normalmente.

Comment: Serialização não funciona assim. Você precisa saber de antemão a quantidade de objetos a serializar na sua lista e desserializar exatamente essa quantidade. Por isso usar serialização tem suas limitações.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2395269/5524514

Comment: @Piovezan Fazendo referência ao tópico https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825958/java-serialization-eofexception-issue , o usuário user207421 responde que não há problema em usar o EOFException para saber que chegou no fim do arquivo e que não é possível ler mais objetos. É isso que eu gostaria de fazer ao invés de ter que saber de antemão a quantidade de objetos.

Comment: no proprio link q vc cita tem uma suposta solucao, ja testou?

Comment: @Articuno Sim, eu já executei linha a linha com depurador. Netbeans, no caso. Mostrou o mesmo erro no console.